# Why is a variable changed within a loop unchanged outside the loop

Tags: bash

I use `command | awk '{ print $1; }' | while read val ; do` to loop through the command output. Recently I wanted to calculate the sum, and I discovered some strange behaviour in `bash`:

**content of test.txt**

```
100
200
300
```

**content of test.sh**

```
sum='0'
cat test.txt | awk '{ print $1; }' | while read val ; do
        sum=`expr $sum + $val`
        echo "sum is now: $sum"
done

echo "FINAL SUM: $sum"
```

**output from executing test.sh**

```
sum is now: 100
sum is now: 300
sum is now: 600
FINAL SUM: 0
```

the final sum should be 600. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on what newfurniturey states, but in a way where you can use it with an arbritary input command, not just `cat`:

```
sum='0' 
while read val ; do
     sum=`expr $sum + $val`
     echo "sum is now: $sum" 
done < <(cat test.txt | awk '{ print $1 }')
echo "FINAL SUM: $sum"
```

Replace `cat test.txt` with whatever command which outputs the input you require.

Comment: +1.  I'll just add to this, that the documentation for what's going on here is on the [**`bash` man page**](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bash&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+Ports&arch=default&format=html#EXPANSION) in a section entitled "[*Process Substitution*](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#PROCESS-SUB)".

Answer (score 2):

The cause is the use of `cat`, which spawns another subshell. This means that the `sum` variable is incremented in the second subshell, and then goes out of scope (and returns to it's previous value of `0`) when the loop is finished.

Try updating your loop to *not* use `cat`:

```
sum='0'
while read val ; do
        sum=`expr $sum + $val`
        echo "sum is now: $sum"
done < test.txt

echo "FINAL SUM: $sum"
```

If you don't actually *need* the loop (i.e. - if you're not handling any other column/content-processing), you could use `awk` directly and store it's value into the `sum` variable:

```
sum=`awk '{ sum += $1; } END { print sum }' test.txt`;
```

Comment: The OP wished to pre-process the input with awk, to do this you can replace the closing line of the while loop with `done < <(awk '{ print $1 }' test.txt)`

Comment: @imp25 The contents of the sample file only contain a single column - so `awk '{print $1}'` is redundant; however, my updated answer allows the full use of that *without* the need for a loop (considering the OP doesn't need any additional processing inside the loop).

Comment: as i told in my case it is not really a cat command. i just used the cat to illustrate my problem

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for the bash pipe. You can do it all with `awk`:

```
awk '{sum+= $1; printf "The sum is now: %s\n", sum } END { print "FINAL SUM:", sum }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
The sum is now: 100
The sum is now: 300
The sum is now: 600
FINAL SUM: 600
```

Comment: +1.  Pipes are a powerful tool, not to be used by those who don't understand them.  Awk, however, should be used by everybody.  :)

Answer (score 0):

This strange behaviour is actually caused by the bash pipes

To quote the [Bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines)

> Each command in a pipeline is executed in its own subshell

Think of `sum` as a local variable in your while loop, that's why `sum` appears not to be set when you go out of the while-loop.

The solutions proposed by the others will work fine.